# npm related errors on Windows 10

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

I keep getting npm related errors on various operations, and even on basic ones such as npm -v.
Here is a an example of such an error:

```
C:\Users\Games>npm -v
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Callback called more than once.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Games\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-23T19_31_19_241Z-debug.log
6.12.0
```

While the version is returned for this command, trying to create a react app via npx "create-react-app my-app" fails completely.

Here is a log of one of such errors, which is not very helpful I must say:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'config',
1 verbose cli   'get',
1 verbose cli   'cache',
1 verbose cli   '--parseable'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose exit [ 0, true ]
5 verbose stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
5 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
5 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
5 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
6 verbose cwd C:\dev\Games\Games.Lottery.Web\Games.Lottery.Web
7 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
8 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "config" "get" "cache" "--parseable"
9 verbose node v12.13.0
10 verbose npm  v6.12.0
11 error code ENOENT
12 error syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
13 error path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
14 error errno ENOENT
15 error enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
16 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Would appreciate your help with figuring this out.

Comment: How did you install node.js?

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file in the directory in which you are running these commands? Try running `npm init` if not.

Comment: @Mehdi I had downloaded an msi from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.13.0/node-v12.13.0-x64.msi and just installed it

Comment: @c_sagan I had done it now, still receiving the same errors afterwards and even during the npm init, although as npm -v it still completes successfully.